# Setting hash value (fractions) in ruby and sorting

Tags: ruby, sorting, fractions, rational-number, ruby-hash

I receive the following hash:

```
my_hash = {a:(1/20), b:(1/26)}
```

But when I see the hash I get the following:

```
irb(main):019:0> my_hash = {a:(1/20), b:(1/26)}
=> {:a=>0, :b=>0}
irb(main):020:0> my_hash
=> {:a=>0, :b=>0}
```

As you can see it convert to Integer (0)

How can I leave as Rational, or float so I can sort `my_hash.sort_by {|key, value| value}`?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for a [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Rational.html) literal in Ruby is `<numerator>/<denominator>r`, e.g. `1/2r` or `23/42r`. What you have is just integer division: `1` divided by `20` is `0`.

```
my_hash = { a: 1/20r, b: 1/26r }
#=> { :a => (1/20), :b => (1/26) }
```

It looks like you might be a Smalltalk or Scheme programmer, but in those languages the situation is different: they had rational literals from the beginning, Ruby only got them later, and so it needs an explicit annotation (the `r` suffix) to tell rational literals apart from just integer division; otherwise you would break existing programs.

Comment: I would do this (.to_r) or r if I was defining the hash, but I receive the hash, and when I try to sort I got all wrong.

Comment: Jorg, I've never coded in Smaltalk or Scheme. I am having this trouble trying to solve one problem at Codewars.

Answer (score 1):

Define as such:

```
my_hash = {a:(1.0/20.0), b:(1.0/26.0)}
```

Or alternatively:

```
my_hash = {a:(1.to_f/20.to_f), b:(1.to_f/26.to_f)}
```